# Analyze array in Excel

Tags: arrays, excel, excel-formula

So, I have a data set with revenues by day, a running total, running total as percentage of a goal, and percentage of the month that corresponds with each day. I use conditional formatting in excel to show which days running total revenues were not within a budgeted variance of 10% of the percentage of the month that has occurred. My goal is to get a count of days that are not within 10% of the respective goal. I know that excel has the potential to analyze an array in the "background" and output a result based on criteria, but I cannot remember how to do so. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use COUNTIFS() with the criteria as the upper and lower limits.

Comment: From your somewhat vague description I have a feeling that you might be talking about pivot tables. No other idea of what you mean by 'analyze an array in the "background"'. Could you expand on that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `COUNTIF()` function like this:

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A10;">0.1")
```